# Controlling the VCS command line when using PeekPokeTester

Tags: chisel

Is there a way to specify options to VCS when using the PeekPokeTester?
In particular, I would like to:
1) Enable System Verilog for black box code
2) Control the macro defines to disable the random number-based initialization. (I want to see initialization issues as Xs.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is currently and unfortunately no. In determining this to be the answer I think making this possible would be pretty simple.  I have created an issue [chisel testers issues 148](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers/issues/148).  Let me know what the priority is